# JavaFX TableView property binding in another thread

Tags: multithreading, javafx, properties, binding, tableview

I have a program that works with SQLite and JDBC.
That's how i get List<> for TableView policyTable:

```
class GetAllPoliciesTask extends Task {

@Override
public ObservableList<Policy> call()  {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList
            (Datasource.getInstance().queryPoliciesForMainTable());
}
```

That's how i connect it with TableView:

```
@FXML
public void getPolicies(){
    Task<ObservableList<Policy>> task = new GetAllPoliciesTask();
    policyTable.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
}
```

It's all working good, but i want to add some functionality - after data is loaded from Datasource and binded with TableView, i want to select last selected row in TableView. And that is where problems start. I can't get access to TableView. I tried use join(), but it doesn't help:

```
private int selectedPolicyIndex = -1;

@FXML
public void getPolicies(){
    Task<ObservableList<Policy>> task = new GetAllPoliciesTask();
    policyTable.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(selectedPolicyIndex >= 0){
        policyTable.getSelectionModel().select(selectedPolicyIndex);
    }
}
```

Like TableView is "locked" or in some progress. Can you please help me?

Comment: Use `task.setOnSucceeded` and put the selection code in that handler. You might also want to set the items of the `policyTable` in there as well, rather than binding to the `value` property. The binding will likely cause the `Task` to stay in memory even after it completes. And the reason why `join` doesn't work is because it blocks the _JavaFX Application Thread_, preventing it from doing any GUI related things.

Comment: Thank you @Slaw ! task.setOnSucceeded helped!